# Como descobrir o número de linhas e colunas de uma matriz criada dinamicamente?

Tags: c, alocação

Com base nos meus conhecimentos, eu criei uma função que retorna uma matriz inicializada:

```
int** initMatriz(int rows, int cols){
    int i,j;
    int** matriz;

    //aloca memoria para todas as linhas
    matriz = (int**) malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i < rows ; i++){
        //para cada linha eu aloco o nmr de colunas
        matriz[i] = (int*) malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        //inicializa 
        for(j=0 ; j < cols ; j++){
            matriz[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return matriz;
}
```

No momento de inicializar:

```
int** matriz = initMatriz(rows, cols);
```

A partir desse ponto, como eu descubro o número de linhas e o número de colunas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int** matriz = initMatriz(rows, cols);
> ```
>
> A partir desse ponto, como eu descubro o número de linhas e o número de colunas?

Bem, a resposta está ali mesmo. Basta você olhar para os parâmetros `rows` e `cols` e eles te darão a resposta.

Ok, talvez você queira saber como fazer isso caso você não tenha mais acesso aos valores de `rows` e `cols`. E a resposta é que não dá para fazer isso, ao menos não de forma portável. O valor do ponteiro é um número que diz em qual endereço de memória começa o bloco de memória que foi alocado, mas nada diz sobre o seu tamanho.

Se você conhecer os detalhes profundos da sua implementação de `malloc`, talvez você possa encontrar essa informação nas tabelas de alocação de memória que forem criadas ou em algum outro tipo de informação interna mantida pelo `malloc`. Entretanto, uma solução baseada nisso é inerentemente não-portável.

A solução adotada em quase todos os casos incluem você encapsular o ponteiro para o array e o tamanho do array alocado juntos em uma mesma estrutura para isso. Desta forma, você elimina o problema fundamental que é não ter o tamanho da área alocada juntamente com essa própria área. Por exemplo:

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int** pointer;
} Matriz;

Matriz* initMatriz(int rows, int cols) {
    int i, j;

    // Aloca a memória para todas as linhas.
    int **matriz = (int**) malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Para cada linha, eu aloco o número de colunas.
        matriz[i] = (int*) malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        // Inicializa.
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Matriz *resultado = (Matriz *) malloc(sizeof(Matriz));
    resultado->rows = rows;
    resultado->cols = cols;
    resultado->pointer = matriz;

    return resultado;
}
```

Para destruir uma matriz a fim de liberar memória:

```
void freeMatriz(Matriz *matriz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz->rows; i++) {
        free(matriz->pointer[i]);
    }
    free(matriz->pointer);
    free(matriz);
}
```

Comment: Então Victor valeu pela resposta, eu estava usando essa estrutura ja, mas antes de chegar a usar ela eu tive essa duvida mesmo, pois achei interessante e não conseguia resolver de nenhuma forma. Pois para vetores iniciados normal, é possível achar o numero de posições. através do código sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int), achei q daria certo, mas quando se inicia dinamicamente esse código ja nao serve mais. Mas graças a sua explicação me ajudou bastante a entender.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, o processo de liberação de memória, posso dar o free só na matriz? `free(matriz)` ou preciso dar um free primeiro no `pointer` e depois na matriz?

Comment: @Skywalker Para usar o `free`, o processo é simples (embora encontrar informações explicando isso pode não ser): Tudo o que você recebeu do `malloc`, você deve devolver com `free`. Se o `malloc` te deu um ponteiro `x`, então você deve devolver esse mesmo ponteiro com `free` no futuro. Você não deve passar para `free` algo que você não tenha recebido de um `malloc`. Você não deve chamar o `free` mais de uma vez para algum ponteiro recebido de `malloc`. Você não deve se esquecer de chamar o `free` para algo recebido de `malloc`.

Comment: Hum sim, então preciso dar um free para todas as colunas em um for e depois sim para o pointer, e posteriormente para a matriz. certo?

Comment: @Skywalker Ou seja, primeiro você dá um `free(matriz->pointer)` e depois `free(matriz)`. Editei a resposta para mostrar isso.

Comment: perfeito, obrigado @Victor Stafusa