# Grafos - retornar um ponteiro para a matriz de adjacências

Tags: c, matriz

Estou implementando um trabalho de Teoria dos Grafos que se trata sobre o jogo Flood-It que é um problema em inundação em Grafos.

Estou bem no começo e implementado a estrutura do grafo ainda. A estrutura do mesmo é:

```
typedef struct {
    int V; 
    int A; 
    int **adj; 
} Grafo;
```

O terceiro campo deve ser um ponteiro para a matriz de adjacências do grafo. A função que cria a matriz é a seguinte:

```
static int ** MATRIZADJint(int linhas,const int colunas, int valor){
    int **m = malloc(linhas * sizeof(int *)); // aloca linhas
    for (vertice i = 0; i < colunas; ++i)
        m[i] = malloc(colunas * sizeof(int)); // aloca colunas
    for (vertice i = 0; i < linhas; ++i)
        for (vertice j = 0; j < colunas; ++j)
            m[i][j] = valor; // preenche a matriz de adjacencias inicialmente com 0's
    return m;
}
```

Infelizmente o Visual Studio não está aceitando a implementação, apresentando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> malloc - um valor de tipo "void *" não pode ser utilizado para inicializar uma entidade do tipo "int **" 
>   = - um valor de tipo "void *" não pode ser utilizado para inicializar uma entidade do tipo "int **"

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95784/132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer um cast para o tipo correto no `malloc`:

```
static int ** MATRIZADJint(int linhas, const int colunas, int valor) {
    int **m = (int **) malloc(linhas * sizeof(int *)); // aloca linhas
    for (int i = 0; i < colunas; ++i) {
        m[i] = (int *) malloc(colunas * sizeof(int)); // aloca colunas
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; ++j) {
            m[i][j] = valor; // preenche a matriz de adjacencias inicialmente com 0's
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Isso acontece porque há alguns poucos casos onde C++ não é compatível com C e esse é um deles. A função `malloc` tem um tipo de retorno `void *`. O C aceita que um `void *` seja atribuído a qualquer ponteiro sem problemas, mas o C++ exige o cast.

Também não entendi porque você declarou as variáveis dos laços `for` com `vertice` ao invés de `int`.

Além disso, recomendo fortemente o uso de `{` e `}` nos laços `for` para evitar certos tipos de problemas e surpresas desagradáveis. Mas isso daí já seria assunto para uma outra questão.

Comment: Muito obrigado. No cabeçalho tem um #define vertice int, por isso! Obrigado pelo conselho para os laços também! Muito obrigado de verdade

Comment: @ThiagoRoberto Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 